# Change stored procedure based on input parameters

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, search

I'm writing an 'advanced search' page for a web application. It basically has a form that goes:

> Search for **query** in the forum **forum name** posted by
>   **username** in the last **date**

The idea is that users can leave fields blank if they wish and the search won't include it.

I'd rather not write a stored procedure for searching based on every possible combination of leaving values blank. Is there a way I can write a stored procedure so that the search changes based on which parameters passed in are blank?

Something like (pseudo code)

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Message = @query

(if @username isn't null)
AND Username = @Username

(if @forum isn't null)
AND Forum = @forum
```

..and so on.

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Comment: I think it should help:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/532468/ignoring-a-null-parameter-in-t-sql

Comment: [Dynamic Search conditions in T-SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html) - Erland Sommarskog's done all the hard work to work out what works best.

Comment: Thank you very much for all the advice - I'll try it tonight and see how it goes.

Comment: @Damien: So that the rest of us could take some rest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable
WHERE   (Message = @query OR @query IS NULL)
AND     (Forum = @forum OR @forum IS NULL)
AND     (Username = @username OR @username IS NULL)
AND     (LastDate = @lastdate OR @lastdate IS NULL)
```

Comment: This approach can cause a performance hit, expecially if there are a lot of optional parameters. See Iwo Kucharski's comment above for a more robust solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
  CREATE Proc [dbo].[sp_sarch_with_filter]                   
  @param1 varchar(50)=NULL,                                
  @param2 varchar(50)=NULL,                                
  @param3 varchar(50)=NULL,                                

  AS                                  
  Begin                                                                  

  Declare @dynamicsql varchar(max)                  



  Set @dynamicsql='select  * from tabelName where 1=1'                               


  if(@param1 is not null and @param1  <> '')                  
  Set @dynamicsql=@dynamicsql+' and col1 like''%'+@param1 +'%'''                  

  if(@param2 is not null and @param2  <> '')                  
  Set @dynamicsql=@dynamicsql+' and col2 like''%'+@param2 +'%'''                  

  if(@param3 is not null and @param3  <> '')                  
  Set @dynamicsql=@dynamicsql+' and col3 like''%'+@param3 +'%'''                  


  Set @dynamicsql=@dynamicsql+' Order by col4 Desc'

  Print @dynamicsql                  

  Execute(@dynamicsql)
```

Comment: This is not recommended, as it is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10-2017_A1-Injection

Comment: "like" queries, just like any other query, are very much inject-able when not sanitized. 
In your specific example, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/15579926/416314 for an example injection attack on a "like" statement