# Score search in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm working on a "nice search" for my users.

I'm looking for a way to search some items using the terms and scoring the search on the same SQL-Server query.

I've got some references googling it.

One of the best that I've found was: http://techforpassion.blogspot.com.br/2013/03/how-to-split-comma-separated-string-and.html

And I've copied part of this, using my data, as follows:

```
DECLARE @valueList varchar(255)
DECLARE @pos INT
DECLARE @len INT
DECLARE @value varchar(100)

SET @valueList = 'how,does,it,works'

SET @pos = 0
SET @len = 0

WHILE CHARINDEX(',', @valueList, @pos + 1) > 0
BEGIN
    SET @len = CHARINDEX(',', @valueList, @pos+1) - @pos
    SET @value = SUBSTRING(@valueList, @pos, @len)

    SELECT
        @value AS TERMO
        ,IFAQ.nome AS NOME
        ,IFAQ.faqid AS ID
    FROM
        itemsfaq AS IFAQ
    WHERE
        IFAQ.nome LIKE '%' + @value + '%'

    SET @pos = CHARINDEX(',', @valueList, @pos+@len) +1
END
```

I get the result which is fine, but I don't know how to merge all the data tables in a single table, resulting the score of the item within the name and what else is needed.

The idea was:

1. Get the terms from the searchbar
2. Split it
3. Loop through the words
4. Know what items are displayed in this word, it gets one point
5. At the end, a table showing the items searched, ordered by the score.

The score is a way to show the user the relevance of the item in the actual search.

---- EDIT

[As follows, the image with the actual result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lx1Yp.png)

The expected: All the tables merged, with the score sum. 
Like:

`como, Como funciona o FAQ ; 00000-00000-00000-000; 2;`

Comment: please show sample data and desired result. at the moment `merging all the data tables in a single table resulting to score` does not make sense

Comment: That string splitter is about the absolute worst in terms of performance. There is no need for a loop to do these things. My personal favorite is the one here from Jeff Moden. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/ There are some other excellent choices here. https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings Or if you are on 2016+ there is the new STRING_SPLIT built in.

Comment: You will need full text search. https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1006911/Full-Text-Search-in-SQL

Comment: You implement the search in SQL, remove c# tag

Comment: I have removed the c# and ASP.NET MVC tags since you are only using SQL in your question so it's unrelated

Comment: @maSTAShuFu Ive added the image link bellow the EDIT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that like clauses don't use indexes, slowing down your queries.

Plus : executing T-Sql scripts is time consuming.

You really should look into setting up **full text search**. Not hard to set up and very powerful.

Besides, for safety reasons, you should use parametrized queries.

Comment: `Besides, for safety reasons, you should use parametrized queries.` The code as shown does not appear to have any SQL Injection vulnerabilities. Or am I mistaken?

Comment: Mmm, you're making me doubt now, but see https://stackoverflow.com/a/15579926/4180382

Comment: That link is outside the database (the query is being built into a string and then executed). The OP's code doesn't have that issue.

Comment: @mjwills Why not always use parametrized queries,it avoids this kind of discussions.

Comment: Because your concern is misguided. To write that query, in T-SQL (remember that code is SQL code, not C# code), with a parameterised query, would be considerably more complicated. You'd need to build the query in a string and then execute it via `sp_executesql` and pass in the parameters. And to what end? It doesn't provide any benefits. It likely confuses the execution plan caching. You are right that parameterised queries are useful to mitigate SQL Injection risks. **But there is no risk here**. _If you believe there is a risk here, maybe point to a citation about it?_

Comment: No, it is the code that calls the stored procedure/plain query that needs to be parametrized.We agree that the code from OP cannot live on its own, but needs  to be called somewhere. No risk in the snippet itself, you're right about that!  I'm taking a beer now!